# Splitting Object

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm implementing a interface `setObject` which will accept String, int, double etc. data type where it I will use this in my Insert statement. But when inserting a data in my database it gives me a values `[a,b,c] [a,b,c] [a,b,c]`. How can I avoid this output?

Interface:

```
public interface CallableStatement
{
    ArrayList<Object> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    public void setObject(ArrayList<Object> myList);

}

public class Position implements CallableStatement
{
    String departmentName;
    String departmentType;
    String departmentDescription;

    public Position()
    {
        array();
    }

    public void array()
    {
        ArrayList<Object> myList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        myList.add(departmentName);
        myList.add(departmentType);
        myList.add(departmentDescription);
    }


    @Override
    public void setObject(ArrayList<Object> myList) 
    {
        String query = "{call insertPositions(?,?,?)}";

        try(Connection con = DBUtil.getConnection(DBType.MYSQL);
            java.sql.CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(query);)
                                    //Prepare the stored procedure call
        {
            //Setting the parameters
            cs.setObject(1, myList.toString());
            cs.setObject(2, myList.toString());
            cs.setObject(3, myList.toString());
            cs.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
            System.err.println("Error: "+e.getErrorCode());
            System.err.println("Error: "+e.getSQLState());
        }
    }
}
```

GUI:

```
private void addDepartmentBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    String departmentName = tfDepartmentName.getText();
    String departmentType = tfDepartmentType.getText();
    String departmentDescription = tfDescription.getText();

    ArrayList<Object> addPositionsList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    addPositionsList.add(departmentName);
    addPositionsList.add(departmentType);
    addPositionsList.add(departmentDescription);

    CallableStatement cs = new Position();
    cs.setObject(addPositionsList);

}
```

Comment: Sorry to say that but your code is broken by design in a few ways. Please consider using the Java Persistence API or Spring Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cs.setObject(1, myList.toString());
cs.setObject(2, myList.toString());
cs.setObject(3, myList.toString());
```

But:

```
myList.toString() = [a,b,c]
```

So obviously when you do it like this, you'll get [a,b,c] [a,b,c] [a,b,c] as your three objects.

Instead try

```
cs.setObject(1, myList.get(0).toString());
cs.setObject(2, myList.get(1).toString());
cs.setObject(3, myList.get(2).toString());
```

Comment: I see why I got multiple values in my array. :)

Comment: @Francisunoxx Also, it look like there is a pattern here ... like `cs.setObject(X, myList.get(X-1).toString());` ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the probleme, `cs.setObject(1, myList.toString());`, in fact, you set all the query params to `myList.toString()` which gives the output : `[a,b,c]` for every param. 
You can use `myList.get(index#int)`.

PS: try fixing the positions of objects when inserting them into your list to avoid another order than expected.